# Using With Statement inside function in BigQuery

Tags: sql, function, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Is it possible to have a with statement inside a function in BigQuery?

I know there are several questions about this, but those are about SQL Server not a about BigQuery.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MyFunc(my_var INT)
RETURN INT64 AS 
(
WITH ABC AS (select * from t where t.col = var),
DEF AS (select * from t where t1.col = var),
GHI AS (select * from t where t2.col = var)

SELECT * FROM ABC JOIN DEF USING (...) JOIN GHI USING (...)
 
);

SELECT MY_FUNC(5)
```

However here, I get an error saying unexpected keyword `WITH`. I have looked at other similar questions but they are about SQL Server, which is different from my requirement in bigquery.

Comment: `WITH` _clause_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

1. You have a typo : `RETURN` -> `RETURNS`
2. Add one more parenthesis pair around a select statement. It will make a statement as an expression.
3. Be sure not to return one more rows or have one more columns in your select query. Just return single `INT64` value same as a return type.

Hope this is helpful.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MyFunc(my_var INT)
RETURNS INT64 AS 
((
WITH ABC AS (select * from t where t.col = var),
DEF AS (select * from t where t1.col = var),
GHI AS (select * from t where t2.col = var)

SELECT * FROM ABC JOIN DEF USING (...) JOIN GHI USING (...)
 
));

SELECT MY_FUNC(5);
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. I have another question though: So the variable I am passing in is a date (not int), and I cant post the exact query as this is work related. I am trying to run my function on a range of dates, something like SELECT MyFunc(Val) from unnest(Generate_date_Array(....)) as val, however I am getting the error 'Correlated Subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient join'. When I run on an individual date it works. Can you please tell me how to run it on a date range?